# Forming a graph from an image

Tags: opencv, graph, image-segmentation

I have a colored matrix with all the edges as red green, blue or yellow on a paper. By using opencv Background subtraction i'll be able to get my grid out of the image file, now how can i construct a graph(weighted) with the colored lines as edges and corners as vertices
weights are-

```
red =1,
blue=2,
green=3,
yellow=4 and so on
```

suppose i need to figure out which path will cost me the cheapest and costliest  in case i need to move along these lines.
Image can be found at--"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9iaM9A4g2ebTGhuQzhCMmtxaHM/view?usp=sharing"`

Comment: what is your question? "how to form the graph from image" or "how to find the cheapest path un the grapgh"?

Comment: forming the  graph from image